# Setting connection parameters in Spark configuration

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to read JDBC table into Spark dataframe. Usually we do something like this.

```
val sparkSessionBuiltObject: SparkSession = SparkSession.builder.config(customconfig)
    .master("local[*]")
    .appName("Application")
    .getOrCreate()

 sparkSessionBuiltObject.read
    .jdbc(s"jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=dbname",
          sourceTable,
          jdbcConnectionProperties)
```

While using Casssandra connector or S3 we can set host and authentication in Spark conf and use that configuration to build Spark session like this

```
generatedSparkConf.set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "cassandra_host")
          .set("spark.cassandra.auth.username", "cassandra_username")
          .set("spark.cassandra.auth.password", "cassandra_password")

val sparkSessionBuiltObject: SparkSession = SparkSession.builder.config(customconfig)
    .master("local[*]")
    .appName("Application")
    .getOrCreate()
```

or

```
generatedSparkConf.set("fs.s3a.connection.ssl.enabled",value = "false")
              .set("fs.s3a.endpoint","s3.endpoint")
              .set("fs.s3a.access.key","s3.accessKey")
              .set("fs.s3a.secret.key","s3.secretKey")
```

Is there any way to specify JDBC uri and auth_options in `spark.conf` so that Spark can pick them automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in [Spark Configuration](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#custom-hadoophive-configuration) doc, you can use `spark.hadoop.` prefix to pass any setting to Spark

> ... adding configuration `“spark.hadoop.abc.def=xyz”` represents
> adding hadoop property `“abc.def=xyz”`... They can be considered as
> same as normal spark properties which can be set in
> `$SPARK_HOME/conf/spark-defaults.conf`

I.e., `spark.hadoop.any.setting` can be passed into your application via standard Spark config file or from the command line using `--conf` parameter, and then retrieved in Spark using name `any.setting`.

Answer (score 0):

why not use a config.properties file?

```
val props = new Properties()
props.load(new FileInputStream("config.properties"))
val db_password = props.getProperty("db_password")
```

content of config.properties

```
db_password=xxxxx
```

then submit with --files parameter

```
spark-submit --deploy-mode client --files config.properties --class testConf /home/code/spark/spark_test-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```